# Flutter: Syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer on text search gives wrong results for some pdfs

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, syncfusion, pdf-viewer

The text search functionality for syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer is not working properly. For some pdfs, when the text search is applied, it highlights other words than the word I am searching. Also, when I search something it takes longer to give the search results . Please consider the screenshot attached below for the same. The search functionality gives wrong results for this pdf http://112.196.1.221:9023/pdf/traffic_pub_gen19.pdf

Comment: i am getting the same error, did you find any solutions?